# Trying to Fix the (Auto Search & Auto Sort ) Code with my current HTML code

Tags: javascript

I need some help, actually I am stuck with this school project. I am trying to use the attached code, creating an auto-search website. Initially i have trouble with sorting out the tables, but eventually was fixed. However, i still have the Auto Sort issue. If i search for something, e.g. i search for "1", a list of "1" will appear. However, i wanted the page to auto sort based on the highest value to the lowest (descending). Here are the edited codes: http://plnkr.co/edit/HeFy7mONHCJDweqi03Zp?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL ll a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a.header {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  cursor: default;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <table border="0">
  <tr>
  <td><li><a href="#">2000</a></li></td>
  <td><ll><a href="#">Hotmail</a></ll></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td><li><a href="#">3000</a></td>
  <td><ll><a href="#">Hotmail</a></ll></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td><li><a href="#">1000</a></li></td>
  <td><ll><a href="#">Hotmail</a></ll></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td><li><a href="#">1500</a></li></td>
  <td><ll><a href="#">Hotmail</a></ll></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td><li><a href="#">1400</a></li></td>
  <td><ll><a href="#">Hotmail</a></ll></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td><li><a href="#">2500</a></li></td>
  <td><ll><a href="#">Hotmail</a></ll></td>
  </tr>

    </table>
</ul>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, ll, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    ll = ul.getElementsByTagName("ll");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }

    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide your code in the question, as opposed to an external link :)

Comment: i failed adding the code here, it just doesn't allow me to paste the full code, so alternatively, i have uploaded the script on dropbox. You will see the code immediately upon clicking on the URL. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So am I right that you want to search for a Number (e.g. 2000) and the result should be: 2000 / Hotmail (matching your number)?

Edit: I saw u re not setting the display style for your 'll' elements.

```
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
            ll[i].style.display = ""; // <- this is new
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
            ll[i].style.display = "none"; // <- this is new
        }}
```

Here is the live result: http://plnkr.co/edit/HeFy7mONHCJDweqi03Zp?p=info

Comment: Yes yes, (example) upon searching for 2000, i should see 2000 and Hotmail and nothing else.

Comment: omg thank you so much for helping out! Oh yah, if based on the live results you helped out, is there a way i can auto filter them, showing the lowest value, followed by the highest (descending)? For example, if i type 1 on the search bar, i saw 1000, followed by 1500 and 1400. Is there a way it will auto rearrange for me, showing 1000, 1400 and then 1500? thanks again!

Comment: Sure you can.
=> put all results in an array
=> sort those by their content

Comment: Hi engagekay, i tried sorting out the content in an array, but i only know how to do it by clicking on the button (click the button only sort out automatically for me)- i do not know how to let the page sort out the content automatically everytime i search, can you kindly help me out further based on this script? thx